# Error in SQLServer: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

I would like to insert to Clients table data from two different tables (Surname and name). Moreover I would like to have a third column (email) that is a concatination from the first two. when i try the code hereunder it gives me the following error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value".

```
insert into CLIENTS (LastName,Firstname, EMAIL)
select (select top 150 Surname from Surname order by  NEWID()),
   (select top 150 Name from Name order by Newid()),
   (select concat(concat(FisrtName, LastName),'@novaims.com') from clients);
```

Could you please help me understand where is the problem?

Comment: If you want to combine each surname with each name you have to join surname and name in a single query instead of using three queries. What your statement says is: Insert a new client for each existing client. Use (up to) 150 surnames as last name of each new client. But a client can only have one last name.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is obvious your sub-query can result more than one record. Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 AS val
         UNION ALL
         SELECT val + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  val < 150)
SELECT FisrtName,
       LastName,
       Concat(FisrtName, LastName, '@novaims.com')
FROM   cte
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 Surname FROM Surname ORDER  BY Newid()) s (FisrtName)
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM NAME ORDER  BY Newid()) n (LastName) 
   Option (Maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I tried and it returned the following message "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." and the error was in the first code line

Comment: Yeah, by default it makes only 100 recursions .. Updated check ow

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the table references to the `from` clause.  I think this does what you want:

```
insert into CLIENTS (LastName, Firstname, EMAIL)
    select surname, name, concat(name, surname, '@novaims.com')
    from (select Surname, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
          from Surname
         ) s join
         (select Name, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
          from Name
         )
         on n.seqnum = s.seqnum;
```

Another method uses `apply`:

```
insert into CLIENTS (LastName, Firstname, EMAIL)
    select top 150 s.surname, n.name, concat(n.name, s.surname, '@novaims.com')
    from surname s cross apply
         (select top 1 n.*
          from names n
          order by newid()
         ) n
    order by newid();
```

This is more similar to your original idea.  Do note, though, that the same name can appear more than once.  And the performance should be better for the first version (because the sort is only happening once on each table).

Comment: `select 1 n.*`?